# Where can I get Vrndavana Mahimamrta of Prabodhananda Sarasvati?

Tags: scripture, vaishnavism, gaudiya-vaishnavism

The Vrindavana Mahimamrita is wonderful book by the Gaudiya Acarya Srila Prabodhananda Sarasvati. Where can one find the pdf copy of the book?

Answer (score 1):

The book is available at the following places:

1. https://archive.org/details/vrindavan_mahimamrita
2. [krishnakosh.com](https://hi.krishnakosh.org/%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%83%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A3/%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%83%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%A8_%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%83%E0%A4%A4_-%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B8_%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%83._1)